# i am trying to create a virtual environment in python but I get the error: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec=python3.5

Tags: python, version, virtual, environment

Morining All,

i am trying to create a virtual environment in Python with **virtualenv**, I'm using the command:

```
virtualenv -p python3.5 MyVirtualEnv
```

but I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.5'
```

Now on my Mac (with M1 chip) I have Python 3.8 but I need a virtual environment because I have to use the ZS library that runs only in older python version.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to install python 3.5 in your virtualenv instead install it on your system and then set it as a Project SDK which will install itself all required things in /venv folder.